# Is it possible to update remote tables using synonyms?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My updates do not stop executing, nor do they fail when updating a remote table using synonyms.

For example I have:

```
USE [CRM_Staging]
GO

/****** Object:  Synonym [dbo].[CRM_OpportunityBase]    Script Date: 05/27/2014 16:22:32 ******/
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[CRM_OpportunityBase] FOR [CRMPRODDB].[Training_MSCRM].[dbo].[OpportunityBase]
GO
```

And I am using it in this context:

```
  update o
  set o.createdon=s.createdon
  ,o.modifiedon=s.modifiedon
  ,o.createdby = (case when s.createdby is not null then s.createdby else o.createdby end)
  ,o.modifiedby = (case when s.modifiedby is not null then s.modifiedby else o.modifiedby end)
  from crm_opportunitybase o
  join Opportunity s
  on o.opportunityid=s.OpportunityId
```

However, the query does not stop executing. It just doesn't do anything.

If you go onto the linked server and run it, then it runs without problems.

**Is it possible to update remote tables using synonyms?**

Comment: The synonyms have nothing to do with it. More likely is that the Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC) over linked servers is causing the query to run slowly.

Comment: @Yuck oh really. how would i speed it up?

Comment: It's kind of the nature of using linked servers. My personal rule of thumb for using them is simply, don't. If you absolutely must you could try to put the necessary DML logic into a stored procedure which resides on the destination server and can be invoked by other linked servers.

Comment: btw how did you know this about DTC?

Comment: @Yuck because that's what handles the communication between two servers.